# Updating multiple records that share a many to many relationship fails

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext

## Details

I have 2 tables (Procedures, Surgeons) with a lookup table (ProcSurg) to create a many to many relationship.

```
scar_Requests       scar_Procedures        scar_ProcSurg            scar_Surgeons
-------------       ---------------        -------------            -------------
RequestID      <>   ProcedureID       <>   ProcedureID(fk)   <>     SurgeonID
...                 RequestID              SurgeonID(fk)            ...
                    ...
```

A single request can have multiple procedures and each procedure can have multiple surgeons.

Everything saves correctly until I have 2 procedures each that share the same Surgeon.

```
Error: InvalidOperationException was unhandled
The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.
```

I separated out the code for saving this part of the record to try to isolate my problem..

Addprocedures is a class that contains 1 Procedure and a list of Surgeons

```
class Procedure
{
    public scar_Procedures Procedure { get; set; }
    public List<scar_Surgeons> Surgeons { get; set; }

    public void RemoveSurgeon(int SurgeonID)
    {
        Surgeons.Remove(Surgeons.Where(x => x.SurgeonID == SurgeonID).FirstOrDefault());
    }

    public Procedure()
    {
        Surgeons = new List<scar_Surgeons>();
    }
}
```

Saving code: using DBContext

```
    private void SaveProcSurg()
    {
        using (MCASURGContext db2 = new MCASURGContext())
        {
            foreach (Procedure p in AddProcedures)
            {
                if (p.Procedure.RequestID == 0)
                {
                    p.Procedure.RequestID = ReqID;
                }

                p.Procedure.scar_Surgeons.Clear();

                foreach (scar_Surgeons s in p.Surgeons)
                {
                    if (db2.ChangeTracker.Entries<scar_Surgeons>().Where(x => x.Entity.SurgeonID == s.SurgeonID).FirstOrDefault() == null)
                    {
                        db2.scar_Surgeons.Attach(s);
                    }
                    p.Procedure.scar_Surgeons.Add(s);
                }

                if (p.Procedure.ProcedureID == 0)
                {
                    db2.scar_Procedures.Add(p.Procedure);
                    db2.Entry(p.Procedure).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;
                }
                else
                {
                    db2.scar_Procedures.Attach(p.Procedure);
                    db2.Entry(p.Procedure).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                }
            }
            db2.SaveChanges();
        }
        
    }
```

I've tried several different ways of saving the record and this is the closest I've come to doing it correctly.

I feel like it has something to do with the way I'm attaching the surgeons to the entity and then to the procedure. Any help, idea's or suggestions on where I can find an answer would be great!

I've been searching google endlessly for over a week and I've been trying to wrap my mind around what exactly Entity Framework is doing but I'm still pretty new to this.

### Edited 9/24/2013

Sorry this is the complete code snippet from the comments section with the req variable included

```
 //Internal variable
 private scar_Requests req;
 private List<Procedure> AddProcedures = new List<Procedure>();

 //Gets a scar_Request from the DB
    private void GetRequest()
    {
        using (MCASURGContext db = new MCASURGContext())
        {
            req = db.scar_Requests.Include("scar_Procedures.scar_Surgeons").Include("scar_Status").Include("scar_Users.scar_Service").Where(x => x.RequestID == ReqID).FirstOrDefault();

            foreach (scar_Procedures p in req.scar_Procedures) { AddProcedures.Add(new Procedure() { Proc = p, Surgeons = p.scar_Surgeons.ToList() }); }
        }
}
```

Comment: The objects in the `AddProcedures` collection (and/or their child objects) are possibly attached to another context. Where do you get `AddProcedures` from? Did you load it from the DB in another context that is not yet disposed?

Comment: using (MCASURGContext db = new MCASURGContext())
{
foreach (scar_Procedures p in req.scar_Procedures) 
{ 
AddProcedures.Add(new Procedure() { Procedure = p, Surgeons = p.scar_Surgeons.ToList() }); 
}
}

Above is how I get the data from the DB. Every call to the DB is wrapped in a Using(dbcontext) block.

Comment: I don't see that you use `db` in the using block. There is a variable called `req`. Could you please use the "edit" link below your question to add such details directly to your question. Code snippets are hard to read in the comments here.

Comment: Sorry details updated above. Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping with good form I'll post my answer since I think I figured it out. Maybe it will help someone in the future.

I completely re-wrote the saving and cut out a lot of useless code that I was using before and less calls to the DB. There was other methods that I didn't post above that saved other parts of the record that I condensed into a single method.

Basically I get the record and its joined tables from the DB and iterate through all the fields/joined tables that need to be updated and save it back to the DB. (Seems super obvious now but I tried this way before and I must have had something wrong because it didn't work the first few times I tried it this way.)

I don't know if its 100% correct or written up to normal coding standards and I still have some final tweaking to do before its completely done.

```
    private void SaveProcSurg()
    {
        using (MCASURGContext db2 = new MCASURGContext())
        {

            //Get Record from DB
            scar_Requests sReq = db2.scar_Requests.Include("scar_Users").Include("scar_Status").Include("scar_Procedures.scar_Surgeons").Where(x => x.RequestID == ReqID).FirstOrDefault();

            //Update Record fields
            sReq.CreationDate = req.CreationDate == null ? DateTime.Now : req.CreationDate = req.CreationDate;
            sReq.DateOfSurgery = dtpDateOfSurgery.Value;
            sReq.IsDeleted = false;
            sReq.IsScheduled = false;
            sReq.LatexAllergy = cbLatexAllergy.Checked;
            sReq.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
            sReq.MRN = txtMRN.Text;
            sReq.PatientName = txtPatientName.Text;
            foreach (RadioButton rb in gbPatientType.Controls) if (rb.Checked == true) sReq.PatientType = rb.Text;
            sReq.PreOpDiagnosis = txtPreOpDiag.Text;
            sReq.PrimarySurgeon = txtPrimarySurgeon.Text;
            sReq.PrivateComment = txtPrivateComment.Text;
            sReq.PublicComment = txtPublicComment.Text;
            sReq.RequestID = ReqID;
            sReq.StatusID = req.StatusID;
            sReq.UserID = req.UserID;

            //Update Users/Status
            sReq.scar_Users = db2.scar_Users.Where(x => x.UserID == sReq.UserID).FirstOrDefault();
            sReq.scar_Status = db2.scar_Status.Where(x => x.StatusID == req.StatusID).FirstOrDefault();


            //Attach to DBContext
            db2.scar_Requests.Attach(sReq);


            //Update Procedures
            foreach (Procedure p in AddProcedures)
            {
                scar_Procedures pro = sReq.scar_Procedures.Where(x => x.ProcedureID == p.Proc.ProcedureID && p.Proc.ProcedureID != 0).FirstOrDefault();
                if (pro != null)
                {
                    pro.EnRecovery = p.Proc.EnRecovery;
                    pro.IsPrimary = p.Proc.IsPrimary;
                    pro.Laterality = p.Proc.Laterality;
                    pro.OrthoFastTrack = p.Proc.OrthoFastTrack;
                    pro.ProcedureID = p.Proc.ProcedureID;
                    pro.ProcedureText = p.Proc.ProcedureText;
                    pro.RequestID = ReqID;
                    pro.Site = p.Proc.Site;
                }
                else
                {
                    pro = new scar_Procedures();
                    pro.EnRecovery = p.Proc.EnRecovery;
                    pro.IsPrimary = p.Proc.IsPrimary;
                    pro.Laterality = p.Proc.Laterality;
                    pro.OrthoFastTrack = p.Proc.OrthoFastTrack;
                    pro.ProcedureID = p.Proc.ProcedureID;
                    pro.ProcedureText = p.Proc.ProcedureText;
                    pro.RequestID = ReqID;
                    pro.Site = p.Proc.Site; ;

                    pro.scar_Requests = sReq;
                }

                //Update Surgeons
                pro.scar_Surgeons.Clear();
                foreach (scar_Surgeons s in p.Surgeons)
                {
                    pro.scar_Surgeons.Add(db2.scar_Surgeons.Where(x=> x.SurgeonID == s.SurgeonID).FirstOrDefault());
                }
            }


            //Set State and Save
            db2.Entry(sReq).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db2.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```